# Android SpeechRecognizer not working with Chinese

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I can't get the SpeechRecognizer to work with Chinese even though I have the language downloaded under "Offline Voice Recognition" under google settings.

Other languages like English work fine. I am currently trying to set the language as such:

```
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh-CN")
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work - I have tried every combination, including `zh`, `zh-CN`, `cmn-Hans-CN`, etc.

On my AVD Pixel 8 with API 34 I get error code 12 which is ERROR_LANGUAGE_NOT_SUPPORTED
On my physical device, a OnePlus 6T running Android 11 I get error code 5 which is ERROR_CLIENT.

Is there any way I can get more information out in other logs or similar? Have also tried the following:

```
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "zh-CN");
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "zh-CN");
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "zh-CN");
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES, "zh-CN");
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, "zh-CN");
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, "zh-CN");
putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS, "zh-CN");
```

But it makes no difference. I have only managed to have it run with Chinese (although with poor quality recognitions) on my old Nexus 5X running Android 6 when using `cmn-Hans-CN`.

Interestingly also when sending a Broadcast with intent `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS` I receive the list of supported languages on the Nexus 5x but not on the AVD Pixel 8 - the results bundle is entirely empty. On the OnePlus it doesn't even log as receiving the broadcast at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.